# How to organize classes in namespaces?

Tags: powershell, class, namespaces, powershell-5.0

Didn't find any information it by googling. Is it possible to somehow organize own PowerShell 5 classes in namespaces?

Comment: Not yet. Guess it's not that easy? Currently there's only `using namespace .........`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, at the end I used the layout/code described under this [link](https://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Building-A-PowerShell-Module/). To import the classes I had to use `using module ..\..\Classes`. As described [here](http://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules) I couldn't use `Import-Module`, since this cmdlet won't import any classes.